# Use captured variable as global in lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it a good idea to use captured variable like this (to avoid having private field):

```
static MyContentControl()
{
    var a = false;
    ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AnimatedContent), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
    {
        if (a)
        {
            a = false;
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            a = true;
            ...
        }
    }));
}
```

While it works my concerns are what is happening behind (maybe there is a performance inefficient mechanism exists behind to make this happens). Because value of `a` can be set after lambda is defined, or, well, `a` can be used in multiple lambdas. Maybe it become `volatile` or something?

Shall I keep it or shall I rather use private static field?

Comment: Where does a private static variable add any meaning that a local one won´t in this case? It won´t matter that much I guess.